# Is Dask distrubuted client thread-safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, dask, aiohttp

Can i use distributed Client instance as singleton with multi-threaded environment?

```
# process start
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
  
# thread-1
f = client.submit(some_work)
f.result()

# thread-2
f = client.submit(anothe_work)
f.result()
```

What about using async Dask Client with aiohttp? Should I create client instance for each request? Or for IOLoop thread? Or per process will be enough?

Answer (score 0):

We recommend using Dask asynchronously.  Documentation is here: https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/asynchronous.html

But also yes, most operations on Dask clients are threadsafe.  Using the event loop is smoother though.